# How do I use javascript to get a list of files from my server's '/public/Docs' in my Node.js solution?

Tags: javascript, node.js

On Windows 7. In a proprietary app that contains chromium browser.  Running on Node.js and Express.  In my file 'javascripts/getMyFiles.js' I'm trying to use the following code from: http://nodeexamples.com/2012/09/28/getting-a-directory-listing-using-the-fs-module-in-node-js/

```
    #!/usr/bin/env node

   var fs = require("fs"),
       path = require("path");

   var p = "../"
   fs.readdir(p, function (err, files) {
       if (err) {
           throw err;
       }

       files.map(function (file) {
           return path.join(p, file);
       }).filter(function (file) {
           return fs.statSync(file).isFile();
       }).forEach(function (file) {
           console.log("%s (%s)", file, path.extname(file));
       });
   });
```

I have 3 problems with this code:

1. I get and 'Unexpected token ILLEGAL' error from the '#!/use/bin/end node' line
2. After deleting that first line of code I get the error 'Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined'.  If I move the '...require...' lines to my root app.js file then the object fs is undefined in my getMyFiles.js file.
3. I need to specify which folder to list when my app gets an event

I get that require is not available on the client-side, but I don't want to get a list of files from the client side.  The files I want to list are in the same path as all of my other files, '/public/Docs'.  I can load a known file straight away, but I need to present the user with a list of available documents first.  Any assistance will be most appreciated.

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: It doesn't matter which IDE, anyway `node.exe` will execute the app. Which way are you calling the file that contains the file listing code?

Comment: your shebang shouldn't have any spaces preceding it.

Comment: OP is working on Windows 7, where is it possible to get `/usr/bin/env` from?

Comment: This is for Linux/Unix/OSX operating systems: #!/usr/bin/env node

Comment: Thank you all from responding!  Roecrew: I'm using Sublime Text 2.  Kirill: I was hoping that I could just make an XMLHttpRequest to the folder and get what is displayed in a browser when I enter the path to my files. eyp: Thanks for the info.  That's one more head-screatch off my list!

Comment: Short of getting the node fs to work on the server-side file-system I'll be writing a script to automatically generate an index.html file for each of the folders in my store.